# Default value from another column for lead/lag in Spark Sql

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark

I have a question about the lag(), lead() functions from the `org.apache.spark.sql` package (third version);

I can provide a default value in the third argument if lag() or lead() returns null.

On pure sql, the third argument can be passed both a literal and a column of the table over which the query is performed.

In `org.apache.spark.sql` I can only pass a scalar value literal.

Maybe there is some way in spark java to get instead of null the column of the table on which the query is being executed?

```
dataset
        .withColumn("LAST_NUM_DAY", lag(col("NUM_DAY"),1, -1).over(someSpec))
        .withColumn("NEXT_NUM_DAY", lead(col("NUM_DAY"),1, -1).over(someSpec))
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce` function (also from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`) to return another column if the `lag/lead` expressions returns `null`:

```java
dataset
    .withColumn("LAST_NUM_DAY", coalesce(lag(col("NUM_DAY"),1, -1).over(someSpec), col("DEFAULT_COLUMN")));
```